# How to know, if unmarshell was successful or not

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a route, that will unmarshell the incoming entity into a case class.

```
final case class ProducerMessage(topic: String, event: String, data: spray.json.JsObject)


object ProducerServer {

  private val route: Route =   
    path("producer") {
        post {
          entity(as[ProducerMessage]) { msg =>
            //complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
          }
        }
      }

  def create(): Future[ServerBinding] {
    Http().bindAndHandle(route, getServerIp, getServerPort)
  }

}
```

How do I know, if the process of unmarshell was successfully or not?
When received data is not a valid JSON format, what happen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `entity(as[T])` the `as[T]` is used to summon instance of `FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]` - then depending of the result returned by unmarshaller, `entity` will continue with passing on `T` into closure, or if it will fail the `Directive`.

If you need to do something with the information about rejection, then there are methods like `recover`, which you can call before `apply`.

For instance:

```scala
entity(as[ProducerMessage])
  .map(Right(_): Either[Seq[Rejection], ProducerMessage])
  .recover { rejections =>
    provide(Left(rejections): Either[Seq[Rejection], ProducerMessage]))
  } { value: Either[Seq[Rejection], ProducerMessage] =>
  ...
}
```

should let you see if input was rejected and recover/handle it manually.